# ASP.net MVC 5 Unable to retrieve metadata for

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to ASP.net MVC 5, and I am making a website using entityframework. I have two tables `Employee` and `Department`. Now when I create a model named `DepartmentMembers` which will get a value `Department Name` and `Number of members` after making a method in my controller `EmployeeController` and here is my code

```
public ActionResult DepartmentCount()
    {
        var employees = db.Employees.Include(e => e.Department)
            .GroupBy(d => d.Department.Department_Name).Select(c => new DepartmentMembers
            {
                DepartmentName = c.Key,
                MemberTotal = c.Count()
            }).ToList().OrderByDescending(o => o.MemberTotal);
        return View(employees.ToList());
    }
```

Now when I am trying to add a view with a template `List` and my Data context class as my Connectionstring I am encountering this error

[image]

It seems that the MVC is assuming that the my class `DepartmentMembers` is a table also. How could I make this work?

EDIT 1: Here is my DepartmentMembers class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCusingEntityFramework.Models
{
[NotMapped]
public class DepartmentMembers
{
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public int MemberTotal { get; set; }
}
}
```

After adding the `[NotMapped]` Attribute because this class is not mapped in my table the error message displays this

[image]

Comment: can you please post your `DepartmentMembers` class ?

Comment: @PranavPatel I just posted it, please check it out. I dont think there's a problem with my connection shring. But do you think I should provide it?

Comment: I can not see any PK in your model, in Entity Framework every model requires a primary key. please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909797/5001784 and let me know if still you get the error

Comment: @PranavPatel after adding `[NotMapped]` attribute (because it is not mapped in my database or tables) I encountered another error. Please read my edit.

Comment: have you registered your class with DbContext ?

Comment: @PranavPatel nope. Why do I need to do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148107/discussion-between-pranav-patel-and-vian-ojeda-garcia).